# Views missing filters for existing view. New view shows the filters

Tags: views

I've created a number of views without problem. But when I try to edit them most of the filters provided by other modules are missing:

[image]

When I create a new view the filters are there:

[image]

I've been able to edit them in the past, but only recently has this problem occurred.

Any thoughts on the cause, and also what can be done to fix it?